# Not Asking For permission in android and program directly runs into denied block

Tags: java, android, android-external-storage

Hi So Recently I started coding in android studio and I included dexter for permissions to access user storage but the main concern is that the code is directly showing the message of denied block even without asking for permiisions.PLease help

```
Dexter.withContext(this)
                    .withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    
                    .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Thanks !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
    
                        @Override
                        public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
    
                        @Override
                        public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
                            permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();
                        }
                    })
                    .check();
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe the case that your application doesn't have the permission yet.
Since android 6, some permissions are considered [dangerous permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#dangerous_permissions) and even if you added the required permission to your android manifest, you shouldn't assume that your application have it yet and you should always ask for permissions at runtime before proceeding with the actions that require them.

- if you didn't add the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to the android manifest, it should look like this :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="your.package.name"

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application>
      ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

- if you did add it but still access to external storage is denied then this is how to ask for it at runtime :

1. First initialize an `ActivityResultLauncher` and register it as an activity result which must be before {initialization, `onAttach()`, or `onCreate()`} fragment creation methods, so the only way was to initialize it as a global fragment variable
2. Then when you need to start using external storage, you first use the `ActivityResultLauncher` you initialized before to launch a request for permissions needed.
3. If permissions was granted the callback should continue your work flow naturally, else (temporarily) you should show a toast/Alert dialog message telling user why he can't continue with his action.

```
public class myFragment extends Fragment {
    ...
    ActivityResultLauncher<String> requestPermissionLauncher =
                registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(), isGranted -> {
                    if (isGranted){ 
                        //continue your work flow
                        goDoSomething();}
                    else{
                       // Explain to the user that the feature is unavailable because
                       // the features requires a permission that the user has denied.
                       // At the same time, respect the user's decision. Don't link to
                       // system settings in an effort to convince the user to change
                       // their decision.
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Can't continue without the required permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     }
                });
    public void getNecessaryPermissionsAndDoSomething() {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { 
                //check first if you have the permission or not 
                //if you don't then launch permission request dialog
                requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }else goDoSomething(); //continue your work naturally 
        }
}
```

for more information about this you should check the [android developers documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#request-permission) about requesting permissions at runtime.

---

### update

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
         Log.e("permission","not granted"); 
else Log.e("permission","granted");
```

Comment: Sir my android manifest is looking like this:<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: that won't be a problem as long as you run on a device with api >23, if you want to remove the `sdk-23` part won't cause a problem either, anyway you could try at least to use the the if/else statement to check if you have the permission or not at runtime, like how I just updated my answer, see which logs comes up, if it says granted then your problem isn't that the permission isn't granted

Comment: permission  api restricted should be only used when some permission were deprecated for higher api and got replaced by a newer one that doesn't run on lower api-s, other than that I don't think you should restrict your permission to lower api-s, and `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` works naturally on any api.

Answer (score 0):

me too. Then I check app->manifests->androidmanifests.xml
add the permission app need.
for me: the line 1,2 show you the location, line 3,4 is my add.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```